# Page up/down not scrolling but still working

Tags: keyboard, scrolling

I have this problem which also temporarily happened yesterday, where my PageUp/PageDown keys still physically work but do not scroll.

Using them in combination with modifiers works perfectly: using them with Ctrl still changes tab in Firefox, using Shift can still allow me to scroll in the terminal.

They are still registered as when I press them alone there is some flashing of the current window (in the terminal the cursor blinks, in Firefox the sidebar flashes) but no movement occurs.

Running `xev` when in this state returns some sort of event for the keys:

```
FocusOut event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

But not a `KeyPress`/`KeyRelease` event. Last night this went away by itself, but I'm not really sure what has triggered it nor what has triggered it away.

I'm in Lubuntu 18.04, if that can help.

EDIT: For reference, normally xev returns

```
KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2a00001,
    root 0x5e3, subw 0x0, time 57346975, (652,584), root:(2333,632),
    state 0x0, keycode 117 (keysym 0xff56, Next), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2a00001,
    root 0x5e3, subw 0x0, time 57347127, (652,584), root:(2333,632),
    state 0x0, keycode 117 (keysym 0xff56, Next), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2a00001,
    root 0x5e3, subw 0x0, time 57347575, (652,584), root:(2333,632),
    state 0x0, keycode 112 (keysym 0xff55, Prior), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2a00001,
    root 0x5e3, subw 0x0, time 57347671, (652,584), root:(2333,632),
    state 0x0, keycode 112 (keysym 0xff55, Prior), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

For the two keys.

Comment: I have exactly this issue on Ubuntu 18.04 with page up and page down. For me, `xev` shows the same `FocusOut`, `FocusIn`, and `KeymapNotify`. The keys work properly after reboot, but a day or two later the problem returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this was the fault of Wire. [They registered global shortcuts with PageUp and PageDown which did nothing](https://github.com/wireapp/wire-desktop/issues/2056). It is being fixed.

By reading around the internet, in any case, it looks like this problem happens when there is a global shortcuts of the keys which does nothing. Doesn't really matter who registers it.

Comment: As of Jan. 30, Wire still has this issue when installed via the wire.com repo. However, the `sudo snap install wire` version appears to be more up-to-date. After changing to the snap install, quite Wire and move your message history via `mv -i .config/Wire snap/wire/current/.config`

Comment: Sorry - I spoke too soon. The `snap` of Wire also still breaks page up/down.